# Spring MVC: @RequestMapping: How to catch Map parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the controller method for processing form submitting:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String submitForm(...){...}
```

But, I have got a new test case:

If Form has parameter `ProductData` call controller method `submitFormWithProductData`. and I am facing difficulties with this, because `ProductData` is a `Map`. On Site `ProductData` field in form tag looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="productData['param1']">
<input type="text" name="productData['param2']">
```

And I don't know, how to create right `@RequestMapping` annotation for `submitFormWithProductData` method.

I have tried:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params="productData")
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params="productData[]")
```

but I didn't get success.

Comment: could you please explain why you want to do this (handling the request differently) ? maybe there is another approach that meets your requirements

Comment: Sure, I can explain: at the moment, I have out of box controller method submitForm; then, I added new feature (productData Map) in existing  html form and I need to process this data to. I am not able to modify oob code, so I just created new method submitFormWithProductData, but how to call it...

Answer (score 2):

`productData` has to be a property of a model object.

```
public class FormModel {
    private Map<String,String> productData = ...;
    ...
}
```

according to this you have to create a handler method like that:

```
@RequestMapping(....)
public String submitFormWithProductData(FormModel formModel) {
  ....
}
```

Spring will automatically bind the productData parameters to the according property in the `FormModel` object.

But I don't know why you want to handle it differently. You could add a hidden input field `productDataSubmitted` and add the following handler:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, params="productDataSubmitted")
```

Comment: You have: FormModel class and submitForm(FormModel) handler - they are out of box, it means, that you can not modify them, ok? You can add FormWithProductDataModel extends FormModel, agree? and add in FormWithProductDataModel  property Map<String, String> productData, agree? then you need to handle this form on server side, you can not to modify default handler, so, you will add new method submitFormWithProductData(FormWithProductDataModel form), yes?  What @RequestMapping parameters you will use for new handler?

Answer (score 1):

Use `@RequestBody Map<String,String> productData` as argument int the controller method.

Here is a [Blog](http://www.beabetterdeveloper.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody.html) and [Read more...](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public void submitForm(@RequestBody Map<String,String> productData, Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}
```