# Map parameter as GET param in Spring REST controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

How I can pass a Map parameter as a GET param in url to Spring REST controller ?

Comment: See this question, and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387877/spring-mvc-requestmapping-how-to-catch-map-parameter

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to catch it with a POST The question was about GET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways (*but a simple `@RequestParam('myMap')Map<String,String>` does not work - maybe not true anymore!*)

The (IMHO) easiest solution is to use a command object then you could use `[key]` in the url to specifiy the map key:

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    public static class Command{
        private Map<String, String> myMap;

        public Map<String, String> getMyMap() {return myMap;}
        public void setMyMap(Map<String, String> myMap) {this.myMap = myMap;}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Command [myMap=" + myMap + "]";
        }
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(Command command) {
        System.out.println(command);
        return null;
    }
}
```

- Request: http://localhost:8080/demo?myMap[line1]=hello&myMap[line2]=world
- Output: `Command [myMap={line1=hello, line2=world}]`

*Tested with Spring Boot 1.2.7*

Comment: Thanks Ralph! What do you think about an approach where we will pass `@PathVariable List<String> map`  and `map` will contain something like this: `12:34,833:73,90:25`   In the controller logic we can split list elements by ":" and get key/value pairs..

Comment: Why do you want to do this, when the "save" solution is so easy? I you want to map it by your own, then you should have a look at matix variables: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-matrix-variables and http://www.captaindebug.com/2013/04/just-what-are-spring-32-matrix.html#.Vj3NmCvMaIg

Comment: because currently I have a following mapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/criteria/{criteriaIds}` where `criteriaIds` is a `@PathVariable List<Long> criteriaIds`.  Right now I need to add double weight to some of `criteriaId` in criteriaIds list.

Answer (score 8):

It’s possible to bind all request parameters in a Map just by adding a Map object after the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public String example(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map){
    String apple = map.get("APPLE");//apple
    String banana = map.get("BANANA");//banana

    return apple + banana;
}
```

Request

> /demo?APPLE=apple&BANANA=banana

Source -- https://reversecoding.net/spring-mvc-requestparam-binding-request-parameters/